# Ring spectra whose homotopy is the ring of ordinary differential operators

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, homotopy-theory

Consider $R=\mathbb{C}[[x]][\frac{d}{dx}]$ as a graded ring (assign $x$ zero weight, and $\frac{d}{dx}$ some non-zero weight). Are there some $A_n$-ring spectra naturally arising in homotopy theory such that $\pi_*X\approx R$?

P.S.: the answer should depend on the weight assigned to $\frac{d}{dx}$. I am not sure what the weight should be (most probably either 1 or 2). I also do not mind adjoining the inverse of $\frac{d}{dx}$ if that is necessary.

Comment: Do you really want $\mathbb C$?  This ring is a bit large from an algebraic perspective.    The ring spectrum $[MU,MU]$ is likely close to what you want.

Comment: @PhilTosteson honestly I only recently began studying this so I am not completely clear about what I want. If switching the field helps, I do not mind (I would prefer to stay in char 0, but if that is not possible, char p is ok)

Comment: The ring of differential operators is not a graded ring when x is placed in degree 0 and d/dx in some non-zero degree. The commutation relation [d/dx, x] = 1 is not homogenous. It is a filtered ring though, and one can consider the corresponding Rees algebra where you adjoin an element h so that [d/dx, x] = h. This is naturally a graded ring.

Comment: @SamGunningham that's true, let's assume we did that

Comment: You might find the paper "Differential operators and the Steenrod algebra" by R.M.W Wood to be relevant. It seems related to Phil Tosteson's comment as well.

Comment: If you want to work in characteristic zero then the homotopy category of rational spectra is just equivalent to the category of graded rational vector spaces, so there isn't really anything interesting to say.